# How can I stop getting CAPTCHAs?

Tags: support, flags, captcha

These CAPTCHAs are very obnoxious. After the 20th completed challenge, it should be obvious that either I'm not a bot, or I've passed the [Turing test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test) and your resistance is futile.

Yes, I post a lot on stackoverflow.com. Does that make me a bot?

I don't mind the normal ones too much.

But the ones where you have to watch a new tile slowly load after every click ... that stuff is absolutely unbearable.

Comment: I've completed [some thousands](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348240) of captchas and they never stopped popping up - which is one of the reasons why I'm not so active anymore

Comment: Oddly, I can never remember having solved a captcha on this site. Maybe it happened once, many years ago. I certainly meet the threshold for being active. I am regularly *rate-limited* by the system, so that cannot be the difference.

Comment: I would think that's because you're a moderator right?

Comment: But then why do you get rate-limited as a moderator ...

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with being a moderator. I didn't get captchas before being elected moderator, and moderators aren't exempted from any of the rate limits either (much to my constant frustration). It is more likely that there are shenanigans going on around your IP address that are giving the system a false positive.

Comment: You could also be running some script or extension that blocks tracking.

Comment: Yea I'm in Brave Browser with uBlock Origin.  Why would stackoverflow of all sites penalize me for that?

Comment: I can't recall ever having seen a captcha on SO, but then I've always used a regular Chrome window so maybe it's something about not being able to establish a universal ID? IMO the system should still be able to recognise an IP range and back off, unless of course it's the opposite that happens and there's a lot of spam traffic coming from a similar range?

Comment: this should be reopened.  SOs 2 year ago captcha policy was nowhere as uselessly nitpicky, on repeatedly the same exact IP, as it is now, so it is not a dupe in a practical sense.